# Sobrecarga de funciones en C++ pasando argumentos por valor o por referencia (Function Overloading)

Tags: c++, c++11, sobrecarga

Suponiendo que tenemos este ejemplo de funciones en C++

```
void foo(int x)  { std::cout << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }
void foo(int& x) { std::cout << "foo(int &)" << std::endl; }
```

¿Existe la posibilidad de diferenciar a qué función deseo invocar realizando alguna modificación en los argumentos de llamada?

Si se invoca la función *foo* en cualquiera de estos modos:

```
foo( 10);

i = 10;
foo( static_cast<const int>(i));

foo( static_cast<const int&>(i)); // Aunque aquí convertir un tipo básico a través de una referencia no tiene mucha utilidad. Sólo es para exponer los casos posibles.
```

Invoca a la primera de las dos funciones sobrecargadas, porque no se puede pasar por referencia un argumento constante a un parámetro no constante.
Pero, ¿cómo se haría para poder invocar a la segunda de las funciones sobrecargadas?
Si realizo la siguiente invocación:

```
int i = 10;
foo( i);
```

Ocurre un error de ambiguedad ya que ambas funciones son válidas para este argumento.

En este enlace https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465379/6717386 expone que una forma de solucionarlo es, en el caso de manejar objetos en lugar de tipos básicos, hacer que el copy constructor sea privado de modo que, al no poder realizar una copia del valor, obligatoriamente tiene que invocar la segunda función y pasar el objeto por referencia. Pero, ¿y con los tipos básicos existe alguna manera? ¿Obligatoriamente se debe cambiar el nombre a las funciones para evitar este tipo de problemas?

Comment: En este enlace se plantean algunas soluciones: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957516/function-overloading-in-c-passing-arguments-by-value-or-by-reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957516/function-overloading-in-c-passing-arguments-by-value-or-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> int i = 10;
> foo( i);
> ```
>
> Ocurre un error de ambiguedad ya que ambas funciones son válidas para este argumento.

Así es, C++ **NO** dispone de ningún mecanismo para distinguir entre la llamada por copia y la llamada por referencia, así que las respuestas a *¿y con los tipos básicos existe alguna manera?* sería un simple no.

---

Pero es una respuesta muy aburrida, así que intentaremos usar herramientas del lenguaje para intentar cumplir el objetivo:

```
void foo(int x)  { std::cout << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }
void foo(int& x) { std::cout << "foo(int &)" << std::endl; }
```

Podemos modificar el comportamiento y saltarnos la ambigüedad usando el operador unario `+`:

```
int i = 10;
foo(+i); // Llamada no ambigua: llama foo(int)
```

Aplicar el operador unario `+` sobre un tipo devuelve su valor, así que la única opción disponible es la llamada a `foo` por copia (¡adios ambigüedad!)... por desgracia esto no nos soluciona la llamada a la versión por referencia no constante.

La única manera de conseguir esto es hacer que una de las dos opciones sea mejor que la otra en caso de ambigüedad, por ejemplo haciendo que una de las funciones sea plantilla:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x)  { std::cout   << "foo(int)"   << std::endl; }
void foo(int& x) { std::cout << "foo(int &)" << std::endl; }

int i = 10;
foo(i);  // Llamada no ambigua: foo(int&) es la mejor opcion
foo(10); // Llamada no ambigua: foo(T) es la mejor opcion
```

Cuando el compilador elige entre una versión plantilla y una no plantilla, la no plantilla es mejor opción, así pues se acaba la ambigüedad; por desgracia esta última opción implica que "*Obligatoriamente se debe cambiar el nombre a las funciones para evitar este tipo de problemas*", entendiendo "nombre de las funciones" por el tipo de las mismas.

Comment: Muy buena opción lo del operador unario, mucho más simple que hacer un casting a const. Y muchas gracias por la información de la decisión del compilador entre plantilla y no plantilla (stackoverflow aún no me deja puntuar mensajes, así que te agradezco por aquí).